# Question on properties of congruence mod $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know it is true that, if for example, $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \bmod 2$, then
$$a^3 + ab^2 + b^3 \equiv 1^3 + 1 \cdot 1^2 + 1^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 2.$$
(I hope this notation is fine, but if not, someone please correct me.)

I'm trying to understand exactly why this is the case. If I worked purely with equivalence classes, I can say that $[a] = [b] = [1]$, so
$$ 
[a^3] + [ab^3] + [b^3] = [a]^3 + [a][b]^3 + [b]^3 = [1]^3 + [1][1]^3 + [1]^3 = [1]
$$
by the rules for adding and multiplying equivalence classes. Alternatively, I could use the following rules iteratively:
$$(a \equiv b \bmod n) \wedge (c \equiv d \bmod n) \implies a + c \equiv b + d \bmod n$$
$$(a \equiv b \bmod n) \wedge (c \equiv d \bmod n) \implies ac \equiv bd \bmod n.$$
So the proof would look like this. We have $a \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. Applying the second rule twice, I get $a^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. Similarly, $b^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. By the first rule, $a^3 + b^3 \equiv 0 \bmod 2$. By the second rule, $b^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ so $ab^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. By the first rule again, $a^3 + ab^2 + b^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$.

My question is: is there another way to understand the shorthand I wrote down in the second line above, or are these the ways to understand it?

Comment: Why would you need another way? Isn't that simple and clear as it is?  But okay, another way to understand it $\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ means "odd" and $\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ means "even".  So if $a$ and $b$ are both odd then $a^3 +ab^2 + b^3$ is odd.  That's all it is saying..... But actually, if we weren't familiar with odd/even $\pmod 2$ *should* be as easy as doing arithmetic.  Knowing that if $a\equiv k \pmod n$ and $b\equiv j \pmod n$ then $a\circ b \equiv k\circ j \pmod n$ for all basic arithmetic functions (not division and not exponents) should be intuitive and *utterly* simple to understand.

Comment: We can break it down a bit further by noting that any product of odd numbers is odd, and any sum of an odd number of odd numbers is odd.

Comment: See the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) in the linked dupe. By inductive extension  to $n$ variables that yields $\,\forall i\!:\,x_i\equiv \bar x_i\Rightarrow f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \equiv f(\bar x_1,\ldots,\bar x_n),\,$ for any polynomial $f$ with *integer* coef's.